# How to use the "exists" function of Squeryl?

Tags: scala, exists, squeryl

I found there is a `exists` function in the document of [Squeryl](http://squeryl.org/functions.html), but I can't find an example of how to use it.

Would someone give me an example of "exists"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/max-l/Squeryl/blob/master/src/test/scala/org/squeryl/test/schooldb/SchoolDb.scala#L1656) (official squeryl example).

```
val studentsWithAnAddress =
  from(students)(s =>
    where(exists(from(addresses)((a) => where(s.addressId === a.id) select(a.id))))
      select(s)
  )
```

Comment: Thanks! Looked for correct usage of "in" operator and found it in mentioned source file.